# Get nsData of video in document directory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I have video in document directory and i simply want to convert it into nsdata

```
 videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Applications/E6B0ACDC-FC72-4EA2-8241-6F7F00F18F2E/Documents/video2015-01-01-04-58-29.mov"];
```

how can i get nsdata?
anyone here who can help me

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: video data = null no data is returning

Comment: are sure about path ? is it right ?

Comment: yup i m sure it. it is playing in mpmovieController

Comment: ok , can you show how the path has been given in mpmoviecontroller ? Is the same as above (hardcoded)?

Comment: @ZohaibkhanNiazi: The hard-coded path won't work. Each time when you open the app, the document directory path will change

Comment: path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/var/mobile/Applications/E6B0ACDC-FC72-4EA2-8241-6F7F00F18F2E/Documents/video2015-01-01-04-58-29.mov"];
  self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:path];

Comment: this will not work because  when you run application again the App id  will change . Follow the answer given below it will work .

Comment: now what should i do  for it

Comment: @v-xtreme thnks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take document directory path using following.

create method which returns document directory path. Never attach Static path. always get document directory path as per following code.

```
NSString *DocumentsDirectoryPath() {NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];return documentsDirectoryPath;}
```

then append your movie path

```
NSUrl *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[DocumentsDirectoryPath() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video2015-01-01-04-58-29.mov"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```